# Multiple Columns in Case Statement

Tags: sql

Hello I am working on a simple case statement in SQL and was wondering if there is a way to search several columns in the when clause.

Something like:

```
Case
When (columnA,ColumnB,ColumnC,..,ColumnZ) = 'Something' Then 'Yes'
Else No
End
```

Where 'Something' is in one of those columns.

Comment: You have to list it one my one.

Comment: @Eric That is the answer I was expecting but I was hoping for something else lol. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want `in`:

```
When 'Something' in (columnA, ColumnB, ColumnC,.., ColumnZ) Then 'Yes'
```

Note that this is an `or` condition, not that all match.

Comment: That is perfect! thanks so much, don't know why I didn't think about just reversing my search like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have to check the condition for each column

```
 Case
    When (columnA =  'Something' OR ColumnB = 'Something'  OR ColumnC =  'Something'   .... OR ColumnZ = 'Something') Then 'Yes'
    Else 'No'
    End
```